# TextView width following curve of ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to do something like this. The width of TextView should follow the curve of ImageView.

[image]

I've searched a lot but couldn't find exactly what I need.Does anyone know a solution to this or any library or doc file which could help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Another way is to use a webview

Answer (score 2):

You can use this **[FlowTextView](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView)**

> A TextView that extends RelativeLayout. The text will wrap around any
>   child views inside the layout.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and let you know. :)

Comment: Hope this helps you .Move ahead